# What is the interaction between hashSet structure, hashCode method and hash buckets?

Tags: java, hash, collections, hashcode, hashset

Please explain the following statement:

> The `hashCode` method is used by the `java.util.HashSet` collection class to group the elements within that set into hash buckets for swift retrieval.

The mentions of hash buckets and retrieval implies that a `HashSet` has some relation to a hash map as the [`HashSet` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) only exposes `add`, `remove` and `contains` methods, no `T retrieve(int hashCode)` method.

Is it true that Hash Set uses hash codes and hash buckets internally? Or is it using Hash Map somehow instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "or is Hash Map used instead"? Your question is very unclear at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question asked in [SCJP Certification](https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=1h1gGT913oNQajXy-jrAiCxgFUbwtjH7kkt5wySI9X34&hl=en) about the `hashcode` method:

> **Q: 20 Which two statements are true about the hashCode method? (Choose two.)**
>
> A. The `hashCode` method for a given class can be used to test for
>   object equality and object inequality for that class.
>
> B. The `hashCode` method is used by the `java.util.SortedSet`
>   collection class to order the elements within that set.
>
> C. The `hashCode` method for a given class can be used to test for
>   object inequality, but NOT object equality, for that class.
>
> D. The only important characteristic of the values returned by a
>   `hashCode` method is that the distribution of values must follow a
>   Gaussian distribution.
>
> E. The hashCode method is used by the `java.util.HashSet` collection
>   class to group the elements within that set into hash buckets for
>   swift retrieval.
>
> *Answer: C, E*

**Explanation:**(This explanation is taken from [here](http://www.searchcrone.com/2011/09/scjp-certification-questions-with-answers-explanation-javaset-3))

> If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then
>   calling the `hashCode()` method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result. It is **NOT** required that if two objects are
>   unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling
>   the `hashCode()` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct
>   integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that
>   producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the
>   performance of hashtables.

Answer (score 0):

The values you add to a `HashSet` are actually set as `keys` of an *underlying* `HashMap`. A `HashSet` uses a `HashMap` under the hood. So, a `HashMap`'s behavior should be expected for a `HashSet` as well.